# c++ and directx11 Depth Test Not working for few objects scene

Tags: c++, directx-11, depth-buffer, depth-testing

I was working on c++ and directx11.. I initiazlized everything correctly.But no matter what i do . The DepthBuffer is not working as expected..

Of the two cubes one cube appears to be transparent from certain angle .And even though the **Second Cube** is very faraway. It always appears as if it is in the front .But when it is close enough it gets rendered over the first cube ..

I dont know what i ma doing wrong here. I am completely fed up :(

Can anyone please be kind enough to help me out ...Please

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <d3dx9effect.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
```

#include

```
// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600


// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backbuffer; // the pointer to our back buffer
ID3D11DepthStencilView * DepthBuffer = 0; // Depth Bufferr Pointer
XMMATRIX g_World;
XMMATRIX g_View;
XMMATRIX g_Projection;
// removed buffers code 
int _Size = 0;


// a struct to define a single vertex
struct VERTEX{FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DXCOLOR Color;};
struct CuxtomVertex{ 
    D3DXVECTOR3 pos;
    D3DXVECTOR3 normal;
    XMFLOAT2 Coord;
    //D3DXCOLOR color;

};
struct Light
{
    XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    XMFLOAT3 Dir;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

// Constant buffer structure
struct ConstantBuffer
{
 XMMATRIX World;
 XMMATRIX View;
 XMMATRIX Project;
 XMFLOAT3 LighDirs[2];
 XMFLOAT4 LightColor[2];
};

// function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void RenderFrame(void);     // renders a single frame
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void InitGraphics(void);    // creates the shape to render
void InitPipeline(HWND);    // loads and prepares the shaders
void InitBoxGraphics(void);

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    /// Irrelavant

    g_World = XMMatrixIdentity();
    g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(XMVectorSet(0,10,-10.0,0),XMVectorSet(0,0,0,0),XMVectorSet(0,1.0,0,0));
    g_Projection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XM_PIDIV2 , SCREEN_WIDTH / (float)SCREEN_HEIGHT,1,1000);

        UINT stride = sizeof(CuxtomVertex);
    UINT offsets = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&B2Vbuffer,&stride,&offsets);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(B2IBuffer,DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT,0);

    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }else{

        RenderFrame();
        }
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;
    UINT MSAAQuality = 0;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                   // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;    // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;                   // set the back buffer width
    scd.BufferDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;                 // set the back buffer height
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;     // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                               // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                              // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                   // windowed/full-screen mode
    scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;    // allow full-screen switching

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                                  D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                  &scd,
                                  &swapchain,
                                  &dev,
                                  NULL,
                                  &devcon);


    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    dev->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,4,&MSAAQuality);


    // Create Dpeth and Stencil buffrer
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthDesc;

    SecureZeroMemory(&depthDesc,sizeof(depthDesc));

    depthDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    depthDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    depthDesc.ArraySize =1;
    depthDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 2;
    depthDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthDesc.MipLevels =1;
    depthDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dpethDesc2;
    SecureZeroMemory(&dpethDesc2,sizeof(dpethDesc2));

    dpethDesc2.Format = depthDesc.Format;
    dpethDesc2.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    dpethDesc2.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    ID3D11Texture2D * depthBufferTEx = 0;
    dev->CreateTexture2D(&depthDesc,NULL,&depthBufferTEx);

    dev->CreateDepthStencilView(depthBufferTEx,&dpethDesc2,&DepthBuffer);
    // set the render target as the back buffer
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer,DepthBuffer);
    // Set the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1;
    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);


    TwInit(TW_DIRECT3D11,dev);
    TwWindowSize(300,800);

    InitPipeline(hWnd);
    InitGraphics();
    InitBoxGraphics();
    InitConstantBuffer();
    _Size = 52;
    InitPlane(_Size);

}

float LerpPos = 0;

// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{


    float LerpTime = 3;
    LerpPos += XM_PIDIV2 * 0.015;


    g_World = XMMatrixRotationY(LerpPos ) *   XMMatrixTranslation(1.0,1.0,1.0) ;
    #pragma region SetUPOLights
    Light lights[2]; SecureZeroMemory(&lights,sizeof(lights));
    lights[0].Dir = XMFLOAT3( -0.577f, 0.577f, -0.577f );
    lights[1].Dir = XMFLOAT3( 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f) ;


    //XMStoreFloat3(&lights[0].Dir,vec3);

    //lights[0].Dir = XMFLOAT3(1,1,1);
    lights[0].Color = XMFLOAT4(1,0,0,1);
    lights[1].Color = XMFLOAT4(1,1,1.0,1);

        //XMStoreFloat3(&lights[1].Pos, XMVectorSet(-40,40,-10,1));


#pragma endregion

    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f));
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(DepthBuffer,D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH,1.0f,0);

    #pragma region Draw Cube
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY::D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(BInputLayout);


        UINT stride  = sizeof(CuxtomVertex);
    UINT offset = 0;

    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&BVBufer,&stride,&offset);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(BIBufffer,DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT,0);


    ConstantBuffer cb;
    cb.World = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
    cb.View = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    cb.Project = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
    cb.LighDirs[1] = lights[1].Dir;
    cb.LightColor[1] = lights[1].Color;

    cb.LightColor[0] = lights[0].Color;cb.LighDirs[0] = lights[0].Dir;
    cb.LightColor[0] = lights[0].Color;

    devcon->UpdateSubresource(g_ConstantBuffer,0,0,&cb,0,0);




    devcon->VSSetShader(BoxVShader,0,0);


    devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0,1,&g_ConstantBuffer);
    devcon->PSSetConstantBuffers(0,1,&g_ConstantBuffer);
    devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0,1,&BoxTex);
    devcon->PSSetSamplers(0,1,&samplerState);

    devcon->PSSetShader(BoxPixelShader,0,0);

    devcon->DrawIndexed(36,0,0);
#pragma endregion
    #pragma region Draw Box2
    g_World = XMMatrixRotationY(LerpPos ) *   XMMatrixTranslation(1.0,1.0 , 14.0) ;


    ConstantBuffer cb2;
    cb2.World = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
    cb2.View = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    cb2.Project = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
    cb2.LighDirs[1] = lights[1].Dir;
    cb2.LightColor[1] = lights[1].Color;
    cb2.LighDirs[0] = lights[0].Dir;
    cb2.LightColor[0] = lights[0].Color;

    devcon->UpdateSubresource(g_ConstantBuffer,0,0,&cb2,0,0);

    devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0,1,&g_ConstantBuffer);
    devcon->PSSetConstantBuffers(0,1,&g_ConstantBuffer);

    devcon->DrawIndexed(36,0,0);  
    #pragma endregion

    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&PlaneBuffer,&stride,&offset);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(PlaneIBuffer,DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT,0);

 *// Draw plane*
    g_World =  XMMatrixTranslation(_Size/2,-6,_Size/2);
    g_World *= XMMatrixRotationX(LerpPos * val)  ;


    devcon->UpdateSubresource(g_ConstantBuffer,0,0,&cb2,0,0);

    devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0,1,&g_ConstantBuffer);
    devcon->PSSetConstantBuffers(0,1,&g_ConstantBuffer);


    devcon->DrawIndexed( (_Size - 1) * (_Size - 1) ,0,0);
    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer


    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}
// this function loads and prepares the shaders
void InitPipeline(HWND hwnd)
{

    ID3D10Blob * BVS = 0,*BPS  = 0;
    ID3D10Blob * BErrorVS,*BErrorPs;

    HRESULT hr1 = CompileShaderFromFile(L"Test.hlsl","Vs","vs_4_0",&BVS); 
    HRESULT hr =  CompileShaderFromFile(L"Test.hlsl","Ps","ps_4_0",&BPS); 

    dev->CreateVertexShader(BVS->GetBufferPointer(),BVS->GetBufferSize(),0,&BoxVShader);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(BPS->GetBufferPointer(),BPS->GetBufferSize(),0,&BoxPixelShader);


       // create the input layout object
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"NORMAL",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,12,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0},
        {"TEXCOORD",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,0,24,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0},


    };
    //SecureZeroMemory(&Bin);
    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied,3,BVS->GetBufferPointer(),BVS->GetBufferSize(),&BInputLayout);

    devcon->VSSetShader(BoxVShader,0,0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(BoxPixelShader,0,0);

    devcon->IASetInputLayout(BInputLayout);
D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(dev,L"seafloor.dds",NULL,NULL,&BoxTex,NULL);

    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerdesc;
    SecureZeroMemory(&samplerdesc,sizeof(samplerdesc));

    samplerdesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE::D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerdesc.AddressV =      D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE::D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
        samplerdesc.AddressW =  D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_MODE::D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
        samplerdesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER::D3D11_FILTER_COMPARISON_MIN_LINEAR_MAG_MIP_POINT;
        samplerdesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_FUNC::D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
        samplerdesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
        samplerdesc.MinLOD = 0;

        dev->CreateSamplerState(&samplerdesc,&samplerState);
}
```

Comment: You need to check for HRESULT failures on Direct3D 11 functions that return them, or you can't know if you "did it correctly" or not. Anything from the debug device?

Comment: Thanks for the tip i will include the HRESULT ... And there were no errors in the debug.. Thanks again

Comment: The HRESULT came out fine . it didnt fail I dont know what am i doing wrong     PLEASE         Any help appriciated .. Please guys i am getting very frustrated

Comment: There are dozens of places in the above posted code where you are not checking HRESULTs. Graphics debugging is challenging, and it's made more so by not checking HRESULTs.

Comment: you are right sorry. I s kinda lazy to go over all of the lines and check for erros.. Sorry ofr my ignorance i will add them thanks

Comment: Hi @Chuck Walboum Thanks for the suggestion. After Adding HRESULT for the depthbuffer creation i found out that problem lied withthe Format..Thanks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphics debugging can be quite challenging as many times you will get 'nothing draws' and there could be any one of a hundred things wrong.

With Direct3D, you should:

- Check the HRESULT of all functions that return an HRESULT (many return void). Be sure to use `SUCCEEDED` or `FAILED` macros rather than equality tests. A common pattern with Windows Store apps, Windows phone apps, and Xbox One apps is to use the `DX::ThrowIfFailed` helper function which is also part of the [Direct3D Win32 Game](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) template.
- Enable the Direct3D Debug device and look for ERRORs or WARNINGs. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) for some other tricks & tips.
- Use traditional 'comment and retry' style debugging to isolate the problem as much as possible.
- Look at using a Graphics Debugger like VS 2013 Express for Windows, VS 2013 Community, or VS 203 Pro+ or something from one of the video IHVs (AMD/ATI, NVIDIA, Intel).